# Double Summation Multiplication

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

There is some simplification, similar to Lagrange's identity, for the multiplication of double summation ?

Double Summation:

$\left( \sum\limits_{\substack{m=1}}^N \sum\limits_{\substack{n=1}}^N a_{mn} \right) \left( \sum\limits_{\substack{m=1}}^N \sum\limits_{\substack{n=1}}^N b_{mn} \right)$

Lagrange's identity:

$\left( \sum\limits_{\substack{m=0}}^N a_{m} \right) \left( \sum\limits_{\substack{m=0}}^N b_{m} \right) = \sum\limits_{\substack{m=0}}^{2N} \sum\limits_{\substack{k=0}}^{m} a_kb_{m-k} - \sum\limits_{\substack{m=0}}^{N-1}\left(a_m\sum\limits_{\substack{k=N+1}}^{2N-m}b_k+b_m\sum\limits_{\substack{k=N+1}}^{2N-m}a_k \right)$

Comment: This is not Lagrange's identity [See wiki for the correct one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity). The identity is correct but the RHS introduces various $a_k,b_k$ with $k>N$, which are not found at the LHS. A simple solution to the question would be to use $p=N(m-1) + n$ and write the double sum over $m,n$ as a single sum over $1\leq p \leq N^2$.